# Issue with context menu on QGLWidget

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qwidget, qtreeview, qglwidget

I have an issue with Custom Context menu on QGLWidget and QTreeView. I have QTreeview and QGLWidget added to a common widget with splitter. I open context menu by the following code.

```
setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
QMenu::exec(actions, mapToGlobal(QPoint(x, y)),actions.at(0),this);
```

actions is a list of QActions.

On mouse press on the QGLWidget, the mouse cursor changes if certain conditions are met. After opening the context menu on right click, if mouse press is done on the one of the menu items, everything is fine. If mouse press does not happen on one of the items of the context menu, the context menu closes and the problem starts. The problem is mouse cursor does not change even if all conditions are satisfied when a mouse press happens. I am not sure if the QWidget lost focus here. So, I have tried setting the focus in the mouse press event. But of not much help. Any suggestions to get over this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reimplementing QGLWidget::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event), to see if it makes a difference?  That's the way I create context menus.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I have tried this to create the context menu in the context menu event but did not go well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem might be that the event is not passed on to the parent widget.
Just add the following statement in you mouseReleaseEvent()

QGLWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);